Proving Uniform Integrability, Tightness, and Convergence of Integrals for Shifted Functions Sequence
I'm working through a problem in Real Analysis using definitions from "Real Analysis" by Royden and Fitzpatrick and would appreciate some assistance. The problem is as follows:
Let $ f $ be a continuous, integrable function on $ \mathbb{R} $, and let $ g $ be a bounded, measurable function on $ \mathbb{R} $. For each $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, define:
$
f_n(x) = f(x + 1/n).
$
I need to prove the following:

Uniform Integrability: Prove that the family $ \{g \cdot f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ is uniformly integrable.

Tightness: Prove that the family $ \{g \cdot f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ is tight.

Convergence of Integrals: Show that
$
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) f_n(x) \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) f(x) \, dx.
   $



Relevant Definitions
From the textbook I'm using, a family $ \mathcal{F} $ of measurable functions on $E $  is said to be tight over $E$ provided for every $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists a measurable subset $ E_0 \subseteq E $ with finite measure such that:
$$
\int_{E \setminus E_0} |f| < \epsilon 
$$
$$
\forall f \in \mathcal{F} 
$$
Additionally, a family $ \mathcal{F} $ of measurable functions on E is said to be uniformly integrable over E provided for each $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists $ \delta > 0 $ such that for each $f \in \mathcal{F}$ , if $ A\subseteq$ $E$ is measurable  with measure $ m(A) < \delta $, we have:
$$
\int_A |f| < \epsilon.
$$

What I've Tried
Problem:
Let $ f $ be a continuous integrable function on $ \mathbb{R} $, and let $ g $ be a bounded measurable function on $ \mathbb{R} $. For each $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, let $ f_n(x) = f(x + 1/n) $.
(a) Prove that $ \{g \cdot f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ is uniformly integrable.
Solution to (a):
For any $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, consider $ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(x) f_n(x)| \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(x) f(x + 1/n)| \, dx $.
Since $ g $ is bounded, there exists $ M > 0 $ such that $ |g(x)| \leq M $ for all $ x \in \mathbb{R} $.
Then,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(x) f_n(x)| \, dx \leq M \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x + 1/n)| \, dx.$$
Let $ u = x + 1/n $, so:
$$
M \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x + 1/n)| \, dx = M \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(u)| \, du = M \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)| \, dx.
$$
Thus,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(x) f_n(x)| \, dx \leq M \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)| \, dx,$$
so $ \{g(x) f_n(x)\} $ is bounded.
Since $ f $ is integrable, we have $ M \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)| \, dx < \infty $, which implies:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(x) f_n(x)| \, dx < \infty.
$$
Thus, $ g(x) f_n(x) $ is integrable. By Proposition 23 (from 4.6) of Royden & Fitzpatrick, for every $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists $ \delta > 0 $ such that for a measurable set $ A \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ with $ m(A) < \delta $, we have:
$$
\int_A |f(x)| \, dx < \epsilon / M.
$$
Now, for any $ n $ and any measurable set $ A \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ with $ m(A) < \delta $, we have:
$$
\int_A |g(x) f_n(x)| \, dx \leq M \int_A |f(x + 1/n)| \, dx = M \int_A |f(u)| \, du.
$$
Using $ u = x + 1/n $, we have:
$$
\int_A |f(x + 1/n)| \, dx = \int_{A + 1/n} |f(u)| \, du = \int_{A} |f(u)| \, du.
$$
As Lebesgue measure is translation invariant, i.e., $ m(A) = m(A + 1/n) $, it follows that:
$$
\int_A |g(x) f_n(x)| \, dx \leq M \int_A |f(u)| \, du < M \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{M} = \epsilon.
$$
Thus, for every $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists $ \delta > 0 $ such that for every measurable set $ A \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ with $ m(A) < \delta $, we have:
$$
\int_A |g(x) f_n(x)| \, dx < \epsilon.
$$
This shows that the sequence $ \{g \cdot f_n\} $ is uniformly integrable.

Problem
Prove that the family $ \{g \cdot f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ is tight.
Solution to (b):
From Part (a), we established that $ \{g \cdot f_n\} $ is bounded in and that, for any $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists $ \delta > 0 $ such that for any measurable set $ A \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ with $ m(A) < \delta $, we have:
$$
\int_A |g \cdot f_n| < \epsilon.
$$
We also know $ g \cdot f_n $ is integrable. Thus, by Proposition 1 of Chapter 5 in Royden & Fitzpatrick, for any $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists a set of finite measure $ E_0 \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ such that:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus E_0} |f(x)| \, dx < \frac{\epsilon}{M},
$$
where $ M > 0 $ is the bound for $ g $.
For any $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, we have:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus E_0} |g(x) f_n(x)| \, dx \leq M \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus E_0} |f(x + 1/n)| \, dx.
$$
Using the translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure, we get:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus E_0} |f(x + 1/n)| \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus E_0} |f(u)| \, du.
$$
Thus:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus E_0} |g(x) f_n(x)| \, dx < M \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{M} = \epsilon.
$$
This shows that for every $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists a measurable set $ E \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ with finite measure such that:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus E} |g(x) f_n(x)| \, dx < \epsilon \quad \forall n.
$$
Therefore, the sequence $ \{g \cdot f_n\} $ is tight.

Problem
Show that
$
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) f_n(x) \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) f(x) \, dx.
   $
Solution to (c):
By the continuity of $ f $, we have:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x + 1/n) = f(x) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
We will now apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem (DCT). Notice that:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} g(x) f_n(x) = g(x) f(x).
$$
Define $ h(x) = M |f(x)| $, where $ M $ is the bound of $ g(x) $. Then:
$$
|g(x) f_n(x)| \leq M |f(x)|.
$$
Since $ f $ is integrable on $ \mathbb{R} $, $ h(x) $ is also integrable.
Given that $ g(x) f_n(x) \to g(x) f(x) $ pointwise and that $ |g(x) f_n(x)| \leq M |f(x)| $, we can apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem to conclude:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) f_n(x) \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lim_{n \to \infty} g(x) f_n(x) \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) f(x) \, dx.
$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) f_n(x) \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) f(x) \, dx,$$
as desired.

Feedback on any portion is welcome.

Where is the problem located in the book?

@Snoop It's not in the book. I'm using the definitions from the book.
